# Which embassy to apply for schengen visa

Tags: schengen

My partner needs to apply for a schengen visa (double entry), we land in france and will spend 4 days and four nights there, then fly out of the schengen area for 18 days then fly back to spain where we will also spend 4 days and four nights, so the total number of days and nights is the same for both schengen countries, but we have slightly more hours totally in spain.

So do we apply at the french emabassy since that is our first stop and we will spend the same amount of days and nights there as we will in spain, or do we apply at the spainish embassy as we have slightly more time there (if they consider total hours) even though that is a second destination?

Thanks!

Comment: from which countries passports do you and your partner possess?

Comment: My partner has an Armenian passport and is living in New Zealand as a resident with me who has an NZ passport

Comment: First country, France because you have two different visits into the \/.Schengen area.